# variables and multiple select statements in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I'm struggling quite hard with some oracle sql syntax. (I'm used to sql server).

I try to use a variable to store a value to use that value again later.

However in a variable block apparently I need to do a select into query (very weird to me), I can't get a screen output.

I managed to write the following query using a temporary table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp
    (leeftijd varchar(30),
     aantal number,
     aantalProcentueel number)
  ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

declare 
  aantalLeden number;
begin
  select count(*) into :aantalLeden
  FROM dbcmnu_all
  WHERE     DBCMNU_ALL.ZF_VP='105' AND DBCMNU_ALL.BEGIN_ZF_VP <= sysdate AND 
          (DBCMNU_ALL.EIND_ZF_VP >= sysdate Or DBCMNU_ALL.EIND_ZF_VP Is Null) 
          AND DBCMNU_ALL.DATDEC Is Null;

select case
    when rijksnummer is null then 'ongeldig'
    when length(rijksnummer) < 6 then 'ongeldig'
    when substr(rijksnummer, 5, 2) <= 0 or  substr(rijksnummer, 5, 2) > 12 then 'ongeldig'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 0 and 9.99 then '0-9'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 10 and 19.99 then '10-19'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 20 and 29.99 then '20-29'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 30 and 39.99 then '30-39'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 40 and 49.99 then '40-49'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 50 and 59.99 then '50-59'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 60 and 69.99 then '60-69'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 70 and 79.99 then '70-79'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 80 and 89.99 then '80-89'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 90 and 99.99 then '90-99'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 >=  100              then '100+'
  end as leeftijd
  , count(*) as aantal
  into temp
FROM dbcmnu_all
WHERE   DBCMNU_ALL.ZF_VP='105' AND DBCMNU_ALL.BEGIN_ZF_VP <= sysdate AND 
        (DBCMNU_ALL.EIND_ZF_VP >= sysdate Or DBCMNU_ALL.EIND_ZF_VP Is Null) 
        AND DBCMNU_ALL.DATDEC Is Null

  group by
  case
    when rijksnummer is null then 'ongeldig'
    when length(rijksnummer) < 6 then 'ongeldig'
    when substr(rijksnummer, 5, 2) <= 0 or  substr(rijksnummer, 5, 2) > 12 then 'ongeldig'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 0 and 9.99 then '0-9'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 10 and 19.99 then '10-19'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 20 and 29.99 then '20-29'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 30 and 39.99 then '30-39'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 40 and 49.99 then '40-49'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 50 and 59.99 then '50-59'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 60 and 69.99 then '60-69'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 70 and 79.99 then '70-79'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 80 and 89.99 then '80-89'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 between 90 and 99.99 then '90-99'
    when months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),to_date(substr(rijksnummer, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12 >=  100              then '100+'
  end
  order by leeftijd;


end;

select leetijd, aantal, aantalProcentueel
 from temp;
```

This query fails it says: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Now how can I declare a variable in oracle sql and use that variable later on in an sql statement?
 (I want to add a column blabla / variable as columnname

I'd also like to have an output to the screen if possible...

Comment: `select into ` is only to put values into a variable you cannot use that to put data into a table. You need to use `insert into temp (..) select .... `

Comment: Also you don't need the colon in `select count(*) into :aantalLeden`. Write `select count(*) into aantalLeden` instead.

Comment: Just one addition: you can select several records into collection variables with `select ... bulk collect into`.

Comment: Where are you running this - all in one go as a script, from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer?

Comment: thanks for the input! I should consider to follow an oracle course, I thought that with sql server knowledge I could manage, but it is harder than I expected

Answer (score 0):

The PLS-00103 is because the PL/SQL parser is trying to interpret the `select` as part of the flow of the block, and it isn't valid there. You need to terminate and execute the block with a `/`:

```
declare 
  aantalLeden number;
begin
  ...
end;
/

select leetijd, aantal, aantalProcentueel
 from temp;
```

@a_horse_with_no_name is right, you should be doing an `insert into`, not a `select into`; and @YaroslavShabalin is right about the extra colon you have, since `aantalLeden` is a local PL/SQL variable, not a bind variable:

```
select count(*) into aantalLeden
FROM dbcmnu_all
WHERE   DBCMNU_ALL.ZF_VP='105' AND DBCMNU_ALL.BEGIN_ZF_VP <= sysdate AND 
        (DBCMNU_ALL.EIND_ZF_VP >= sysdate Or DBCMNU_ALL.EIND_ZF_VP Is Null) 
        AND DBCMNU_ALL.DATDEC Is Null;

insert into temp (leeftijd, aantal number)
select case
    ...
  end as leeftijd
  , count(*) as aantal
from ...
group by ...;
```

There isn't much point having an `order by` clause in a select used for an insert.  I'm not sure what you intend to do with your `aantalLeden` value; it isn't clear if you want to set the `aantalProcentueel` value to that for all rows.

You may not really want a temporary table at all though, it depends what you're going to do with it next.